# Color difference in PNG JPEG file created by jfreechart

Tags: java, image, jsp, jfreechart

I created a bar chart using jfreechart in a jsp

```
String path=null;
 DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset(); 
 dataset.setValue(6, "Profit1", "Jane"); 
 dataset.setValue(3, "Profit2", "Jane"); 
 dataset.setValue(7, "Profit1", "Tom"); 
 dataset.setValue(10, "Profit2", "Tom"); 
 dataset.setValue(8, "Profit1", "Jill"); 
 dataset.setValue(8, "Profit2", "Jill"); 
 dataset.setValue(5, "Profit1", "John"); 
 dataset.setValue(6, "Profit2", "John"); 
 dataset.setValue(12, "Profit1", "Fred"); 
 dataset.setValue(5, "Profit2", "Fred");

 // Profit1, Profit2 represent the row keys 
 // Jane, Tom, Jill, etc. represent the column keys

 JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D( 
    "Comparison between Salesman",  // Chart name 
    "Salesman",                     // X axis label 
    "Value ($)",                    // Y axis value 
    dataset,                        // data set 
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
    true, true, false);
 chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);  
 // Set the background color of the chart    

 // Creating a JPEG image 
 try 
 { 
     path= request.getRealPath("images")+"/myChart.jpg";
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(path), chart, 500, 300);

    System.out.println("image created");
    //path=path.replace("\\","/");
 } 
 catch (IOException e) 
 { 
    System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart."); 
 }
```

the jpeg image created 
[image]

when saved as png image

```
 path= request.getRealPath("images")+"/myChart.png";
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File(path), chart, 500, 300);
```

[image]

I could not find where i go wrong, i need jpeg image as like png image.
Any idea?

Comment: I've no clue on JFreeCharts, but the JPEG colors shows symptoms of JPEG incorrectly stored with alpha (from a `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`) or YCbCr data interpreted as RGB. Look at the source code for JFreeChart to see the type of image and how it's stored, if possible. Are there options to control transparency of the output? Can you control the image type in any way?

Comment: @haraldk Thanks for the reply i can control the transparency but still i couldn't get the clear image